# how to using ThreadPool to run socket thread parallel?

Tags: threadpool

I'm new in network programming and want to create new socket thread base on a request. My thread send request via tcp/ip socket and waiting the response. How can i using threadpool to create and run threads parallel ? Can anyone show me the sample ? Thank !

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx